# Get Logged In User Info Inside Django-tempatetags inclusion tag method?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to render the navigation Menu having Logged In User Name In It by making a user of custom templatetags. PFB the code,

```
@register.inclusion_tag('kpt/navbar.html')
def getmenu( params ):
  raw = params.split("|")
  active_item = raw[0]
  menus = [
    {"name": "Home", "url": "/kpt/", "class":""},
    {"name": "High CPC", "url": "/kpt/hcpc", "class":""},
    {"name": "Trending Keywords", "url": "/kpt/tcpc","class":""}
  ]
  for menu in menus:
    if menu["name"] == str(active_item):
      menu["class"] = "active"
  return {'menus':menus, "user":raw[1] }
```

I want to retrieve the Logged In User Full Name inside this method without having any dependency to pass it from the template as there then I would require to concatenate a variable with a static string, to do so. Which is not supported in Jinja! Something like this:

```
{% getmenu "Home|MD Danish" %}
```

Where MD Danish will be in {{user.get_full_name}}

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You could register `templatetag` as below. Just passing `takes_context=True` where you register your *inclusion_tag*

```
@register.inclusion_tag('kpt/navbar.html', takes_context=True)  # This will get context data from view / template
def getmenu(params):
     # Here you can get user as below
    user = params.request.user
    raw = params.split("|")
      active_item = raw[0]
      menus = [
        {"name": "Home", "url": "/kpt/", "class":""},
        {"name": "High CPC", "url": "/kpt/hcpc", "class":""},
        {"name": "Trending Keywords", "url": "/kpt/tcpc","class":""}
      ]
      for menu in menus:
        if menu["name"] == str(active_item):
          menu["class"] = "active"
      return {'menus':menus, "user":raw[1] }
```

Comment: This is the right approach, but not quite there. With `takes_context=True`, there will be an additional parameter, `context`, which will be a dictionary; so the user is in `context['request'].user`.

Comment: @Daniel  -- yeah I figured it out. You are right. Thanks a lot